# startofday(Timestamp) vs bin(Timestamp, 1d) - any reason to prefer one over the other?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

When I aggregate data to the day, I consistently use e.g. startofday(Timestamp).

I commonly see other people use bin(Timestamp, 1d).

Is there any reason (semantic, performance, or other) to prefer one over the other?

Comment: "bin .. 1d" suggests to me that it's an easy tweak to use 1-hour increments (for instance). You cannot do that with "startofday"

Comment: Change flexibility - good point, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two options are equivalent in terms of semantics and performance